# Шаблон wordpress не выводит абзацы

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте!
Стандартный редактор страниц в wordpress заменяет теги < p > и < br > на двойной перенос строки и одинарный соответственно. Но при выводе функцией the_content(), как я понимаю, используется функция wpautop(), которая выполняет обратную операцию (двойной перенос строки заменяет на тег < p >).
Суть проблемы в том, что при выводе контента функцией the-content() теги < p > и < br > не выводятся, т.е. вместо них также остаются переносы строки. В итоге, на странице, весь текст написан в одну строчку...
Как можно данную проблему исправить?

Вывожу на страницу вот так:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы визуальный редактор сохранял эти теги, или при выводе контента перенос строк заменялся на теги

Comment: Судя по всему кто-то ли что-то (плагин или functions.php) убирает фильтр `wpautop` из контента. Посмотрите наличие `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` в них

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте ручками прогнать контент через функцию `wpautop`:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <?php echo wpautop( get_the_content() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что с помощью функции `wpautop` вы наоборот отключаете автоматическую простановку абзацев. Так что если в function.php у вас есть что-то подобное `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' )`, советую удалить этот код. Тогда все должно выводится правильно.

Answer (score -1):

Стандартный редактор WordPress вполне себе сохраняет `<p>` и `<br>` в записи в базе данных. Вот только вставлять теги нужно в текстовом режиме и не переходить в визуальный режим до сохранения.

При переходе в визуальный режим редактор заменяет теги на переводы строк. Но если перейти затем в текстовый режим и обновить страницу, то из базы загрузится сохраненный текст с тегами.